# MYSql with alias issue

Tags: mysql, alias

referring to: http://pastebin.com/raHbAvRN

My tables:

```
Users:(id, lat, lon, ...)
Favorites:(id, userId, prefId)
```

"my" alias works, but "fav" alias not, can you please help me understanding why?
I need to populate "favorite" column in output with true/false depending if the current "users.id" is in the list of pref ids.

Thank you

Comment: You haven't defined `fav` alias anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
select count(*),
    users.id,
    ...distance(my.lat, my.lon, users.lat, users.lon) as distance,
    case when users.id in (
        select favorites.prefId
       from favorites
       where favorites.userId = ?) then true else false end as favorite
from users,
    (
        select users.lat,
            users.lon
        from users
        where users.id = ?
        ) as my
where...
```